# Ajax can't send data to file in other folder

Tags: php, ajax

In my page I have the following code

**insert.php**

```
<?php 
include ("../config/config.php");   
$state = $_POST['state'];
$squery = mysql_query("INSERT INTO ctm_state(state) VALUES('$state')");
if($squery){
echo "Data for $state inserted successfully!";
}
else{ echo "An error occurred!"; }
?>
```

**state.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#insert").click(function(){
var state=$("#state").val();
$.post('ctmadmin/ajax_state.php', {state: state},
function(data){
$("#message").html(data);
$("#message").hide();
$("#message").fadeIn(1500); //Fade in the data given by the insert.php file
});
return false;
});
});
</script>
```

When the above URL is used, the ajax works fine and shows correct result of inserted data. But if the URL is changed to

$.post('ctmadmin/phpqrcode/ajax_state.php', {state: state},

The ajax_state is in other folder called phpqrcode, when I use the above URL it does not insert the datas into table and dont show anything in frontpage. Anybody can help me to solve this problem

Comment: `$state` SQL Injection warning.

Comment: check include ("config/config.php") statement's relative path. I think it might not be updated when you move it to another folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have moved `insert.php` into a subdirectory then its include will fail because it has a relative path, you could prefix it with `../`:

```
include ("../config/config.php");
```

Comment: Not working I replace the include as include ("../config/config.php");

Comment: Check your error log, and verify that `config.php` is in `ctmadmin/config/config.php`.

Comment: yes. This file is present. But in the above code I misplaced the include. include ("../config/config.php"); isthe current url ctmadmin/ajax_state.php', and if I change my url as ctmadmin/phpqrcode/ajax_state.php what I have to place in inlcude

Comment: Now see my code. Now this is working for me. But If I replace the URL means "ctmadmin/phpqrcode/ajax_state.php", what I have to do